# Get item by DocID using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, document-id

Has anybody retrieved items by their **DocId** using powershell. Specifically the ID generated by the **DocID** service. I'm looking to get details of items based on a (large) list of **DOCIDs**. I guess I could use the search service but wondered if anybody had done something similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using PowerShell you can get it using

```
$site = Get-SPSite http://siteurl
$provider = [Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.DocumentId]::GetProvider($site)
$result = $provider.GetDocumentUrlsById($site, "DocID-1-1")
```